# Creating users in Azure AD via angular using MSAL.js

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

From a Web Applications perspective, is it possible to have a user create an Azure AD account (by providing a email, name, phone number, etc) that the web application can forward to Azure AD?

I am trying to use [MSAL.js for Angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) and following the sample I can have a login popup which prompts me for a Microsoft email via getUser():

From the sample:

```
 constructor(private broadcastService: BroadcastService , private authService : MsalService,   private productService: ProductService)
  {
    //  This is to avoid reload during acquireTokenSilent() because of hidden iframe
    this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener;
   if(this.authService.getUser())
    {
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }
   else {
     this.loggedIn = false;
   }
  }
```

However I feel like I am missing over the part where users get added. Can users only be added by invitation from the Azure portal? Is it possible to programatically add a user to Azure AD by supplying a name, email, phone number, etc and having them have to generate a password on first sign in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[msal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) library that you mention and other similar Microsoft client authentication libraries ([more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries#microsoft-supported-client-libraries)) only help with authenticating users/applications and acquiring to tokens to call protected web API's.

You can look at [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) to add users to Azure AD. So `msal-angular` could help your application to acquire token(s) to authenticate to Microsoft Graph API, which can then provide the needed functionality.

Look at [Create User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) Microsoft Graph API.

**Permissions required**:

Your application will need the relevant permissions to be able to create users in Azure AD. It is a higher privilege to be able to write to Azure AD (as compared to just read information for existing users in order to authenticate them, which is what most common applications need). Make sure your use case really calls for it and secure your application so that only appropriate users are able to access it.

As you mention angular, so if this is an SPA that runs on client browser, you will need to work with `Delegated permissions` only i.e. in context of the signed in user. (`Application permissions` can be used by confidential clients like a backend daemon application but that may not be relevant for your case.)

[image]

Sample request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

**Quick Testing**

[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) - You can use it to quickly test out create user or any other Microsoft Graph APIs for that matter.

[Further code samples](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/angular)

Comment: Thanks Rohit for the great response (and links to further reading). Some followup architecture based questions:

1. So an Azure Subscription by default has its own Azure Active Directory associated with it? So my Microsoft Graph calls will somehow have knowledge to the subscription its accessing?

 What if I had multiple resource groups in my Azure subscription, one per business customer? Would I configure each "business organization" as a "group" in Azure AD and have a single Azure AD "resource" across all my customers?

Comment: @devway You're welcome! **1)** When you call Microsoft Graph API, you'll first acquire a token from Azure AD to authenticate, so it figures out which Azure AD tenant to work with based on token that you provide with call (or else you'll not be authorized) **2)** How to segment for your customers is more subjective, depending on what exactly you're trying to do, it could be a single Azure AD or even separate Azure AD tenant for each one. Multi-tenant applications (SaaS) work that way, but you need to elaborate a bit more on requirements. Plz consider posting a new question for this 2nd part.